# Cadence - Identifying important Operation metrics

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

I am doing some metrics collection and want to do some aggregations based on `Operation`.

1. What would you say are the top 5 (or more or less) operations across all services that we should be focusing on?      OR
2. Are there top 5 (or more or less) for individual services? If yes, can you list them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this question is quite vague. I just made some for my own preference as minimum set of monitors.

### Server metrics

- You should monitor availability & latency of all APIs for every service, and persistence API.
- You should monitor queue latency from history service -- this is the key metric to understand the background task perf which is missing from API availability & latency
- You should make dashboard for API counters for each service so that you can see the load changing over the time

### Client metrics

- You should monitor on Workflow failure/timeout
- You should monitor on Activity task failure/timeout
- You should monitor decision task failure/timeout